# How I can block the execution of an action in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Situation:**

I have a controller (with its associated views), that after it was developed, it was decided that it will be excluded from the current phase, and instead, it will be included in some phase in the future.

I cannot simply exclude or delete the controller and the views from the solution because of what I mentioned that will be using the controller in the future. Something that came to my mind was to force each action on the controller to redirect to the main page if they are accessed, but I think this is not too "elegant".

**Question:**

What other method can I use to block the execution of an action in a controller when they are accessed through the URL?

Comment: You could create a filter (maybe called RedirectFilter) that you could place as an attribute on the controller.  Any controller invoked with this attribute will redirect to whatever controller/action is specified by the filter.  [RedirectFilter(controller="Home", action="Index")]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keeping unused code in your codebase like that is generally a bad idea.  Assuming you have some sort of version control in place, keep a branch around with that controller, but delete it from your master branch.  Merge that branch back in when you're bringing the feature back.

If, however, removing the code really isn't possible, I'd make a custom filter to redirect any requests to that controller to some other URL.

i.e.

```
[RedirectTo("Index", "Home")]
public class MyFutureController : Controller {
...
```

where you have

```
public class RedirectToFilter : ActionFilterAttribute {
   public string RedirectAction { get; set;}
   public string RedirectController { get; set; }

   public RedirectToFilter(string redirectAction, string redirectController) {
      RedirectAction = redirectAction;
      RedirectController = redirectController;
   }

   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
      filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(RedirectAction, RedirectController);    
   }
}
```

Any requests to `FutureController` will just get redirected to your `Home/Index` route.  In the future, you just have to remove the attribute from the controller and you're good to go.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for! The only thing that was not working for me, for some reason was the instruction: filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction(RedirectAction, RedirectController);. However, I changed that instruction for filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = RedirectAction, controller = RedirectController }));, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Although the solution is the answer you were looking for, don't overlook the good advice part of the answer. Make everyone a favor and use source control and remove the unnecessary code, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom route, so that when request comes for this controller it actually redirects to some other controller, e.g. HomeController

Answer (score 1):

Use an OnActionExecuting action filter on the controller.

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Detail()
    {
        return View();
    }

    protected override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction( "Index", "Home" );
    }
```

When you're ready to start using the controller just delete the OnActionExecuting method and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

Just decorate the action method with the `[NonAction]` attribute. More [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.nonactionattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply write a view to display to the user who directs themselves there that it is still under construction or something of the like. Excluding or commenting out the controller is certainly an option, or you could rewrite all associated methods to reroute to another page.

I think the best solution is probably to just exclude it altogether, having it in your application doesn't benefit you or the user if you're not using it currently. The code should remain so you're free to tweak and refine it before you actually get a release version going.